# How to crop Bitmap on all four sides?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I'm trying to write a method that takes a `Bitmap` and the crop values as parameters and returns the cropped `Bitmap`.

My code:

```
public Bitmap applyCrop(Bitmap bitmap, int leftCrop, int topCrop, int rightCrop, int bottomCrop) {
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, leftCrop, topCrop, bitmap.getWidth() - rightCrop, bitmap.getHeight() - bottomCrop);
}
```

Using this code i'm receiving the following `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width()
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case the `Bitmap.createBitmap()` is taking the size of crop image and not the coordinates of the second corner, You should do:

```
public Bitmap applyCrop(Bitmap bitmap, int leftCrop, int topCrop, int rightCrop, int bottomCrop) {
    int cropWidth = bitmap.getWidth() - rightCrop - leftCrop;
    int cropHeight = bitmap.getHeight() - bottomCrop - topCrop;
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, leftCrop, topCrop, cropWidth, cropHeight);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here i have a sample for you. Use this

```
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.abc);


//pass your bitmap here and give desired width and height
newBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0,0,"GIVE WIDTH HERE", "GIVE HEIGHT HERE");
```

Let me know if this works! :)

Comment: i didnt saw your answer !